# Ajax function success does not perform

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Good afternoon.

I am using ajax / json to send a form to a php file. Sending and php execution works well. But the ajax success function does not come into action? Below I describe the code in ajax and php:

Ajax file:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'datacheck.php',
  data: { ws_safe_email : ws_safe_email },
  dataType: 'json',
  //
  beforeSend : function() {
    $('div').hide();
    $('div').text('Analisando Dados, Aguarde...').fadeIn('slow');
  },
  //
  complete : function() {
  },
  //
  success : function(json) {
    var info = json.info;
    alert(info);
  },
  //
  error : function() {
    //
  }
});
```

Php file:

```
<?php  

$ws_safe_email = $_POST["ws_safe_email"];

if ($ws_safe_email == "") {

    $objreply["info"] = "Email vazio ?";
}
else {

    $objreply["info"] = "Email: $ws_safe_email, recebido com sucesso." ;
}

echo json_encode($objreply);
```

Obs: I used the debug browser and confirmed that the php sends the response in JSON format. But the success of Ajax does not get the php response?

Comment: WHat version of the jquery library are you using

Comment: What status is the php response sending? If it's not sending a 200, the success call won't hit. you will also need `var info = JSON.parse(json)` in your method call.

Comment: jquery-3.1.0.js

Comment: @kripple Not as he is using `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: no effect using var info = JSON.parse (json)

Comment: What are you putting in the var `ws_safe_email` before calling ajax

Comment: this code ran perfectly fine and just crashed.

Comment: ws_safe_email = test@test.com

Comment: I assume you mean `ws_safe_email = 'test@test.com';`